# jQuery not working after $ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get data from a php file with jQuery $.post method. After the ajax call i'm appending a button  from php file which will onclick load more posts by removing itself, but after ajax call the jQuery is no longer working.

```
var result = function (str,end)
{
    $.get("query.php",{ start:str, end: end },function(ajaxresult){
    $(ajaxresult).appendTo(".focus");  
    })
}
result(4,0);

$('#loadmore').on('click', function(e){
    result(8,4);
    alert('delete');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.remove();
});

Here is my Php file code.

<?php
$start = $_GET['start'];
$end = $_GET['end'];


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','binarystar','test');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"users");
$sql="SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $end,$start";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<section>";
    echo "<span class='feed_username'>" . $row['username'] ."</span>   ";
    echo "<span class='date'>" . $row['time'] ."</span><br>";
    echo "<span class='postx'>" . $row['post'] ."</span><br>";
    echo "</section>";

}
echo "<button id='loadmore'>Load More Posts</button>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: This isn't pertinent to your question, but consider using PDO for security and performance in doing your MySQL queries. http://us2.php.net/pdo_mysql

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` is unique, you need to use class instead:

```
echo "<button class='loadmore'>Load More Posts</button>";
```

Then you can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically loaded elements:

```
$('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: How do you know the button isn't already inside .focus, and is overwritten by the new content, that way the ID would be unique in the document ?